# Chrome Extension to analyze page source code for a number in a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a Chrome extension that is fairly complex so I'm just looking for a high level overview of how I should approach this. Keep in mind I'm brand new to Chrome Extensions.

I need an extension that will analyze the source code of a page, and specifically monitor a number that is in a div on that page. Whenever that number gets over a certain threshold, I will need to take some sort of action (popup, alert, etc).

The source page is refreshed automatically every few seconds with updated info so I will need the extension to run every few seconds as well to capture the most updated data.

As an overview, I'm looking for suggestions on how to do the following:

1. Retrieve page source for a non-active tab, every 5 seconds. It should run in the background and not need to be "clicked" to be functioning.
2. Look into that source code to find what number is in a specific div.
3. Create some sort of alert or notification if that number exceeds a certain threshold.

I have seen various posts about how to get the source of an active page, but nothing about storing that source code to be analyzed. Also, I'm not sure how I should go about looking within the source code (I saw some JQuery recommendations).

One last thought: I was hoping this would be a relatively lightweight extension. Is running through this process every 5/10/15 seconds going to be resource intensive?

Comment: Do you really mean that static HTML source changes, and not a dynamic change made by the page's JavaScript? This is **extremely important** even for a high-level overview answer.

Comment: The changes are made by pages Javascript. Thanks for the clarification @Xan

Comment: By "non-active", I assume it's still okay to create the tab and it can be visible just that it can't steal the focus, is that correct?

Comment: Absolutely - so the tab will be open to the page, but the person would be working in another tab in the same browser @donaddon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the change to the DIV is being made with Javascript in the page, you will have to actually load the page with the rendering engine (not just load the page source) and then look at the DIV element to see if the content has changed.

You can do this easily with a content script.  Create a content script that will run in the page that you wish to load (by setting the URL with the "matches" parameter in the manifest.json).

The in-page content script can read the DIV periodically with something like this:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    var THRESHOLD = 100;
    var div = document.getElementById("theDiv");
    var num = parseInt(div.innerText);
    if (num > THRESHOLD) {
        alert('The number is: ' + num);
    }
    // If you need to reload the page itself to check the number
    // then just reload the page on a regular interval
    window.location.reload();  
}, 10000);
```

You can then load the page once from the background page in a non-selected tab:

```
chrome.tabs.create({ selected: false, url: 'http://www.theurl.com' })
```

Alternatively, if the page allows framing, you could create an iframe in your background page and load the page invisibly within your background page:

```
var frame = document.createElement("iframe");
frame.src = 'http://www.theurl.com';
document.body.appendChild(frame);
```

But to do this in an iframe you will have to ensure that your content script has the "all_frames" value set to true in the manifest.json.

Comment: Alternatively, one can try keeping the page in an `<iframe>` in the background page itself.

Comment: It used to be the case that content scripts would not run in an iframe in the background page, but that appears to work correctly now.  Good idea @Xan, I'll edit my response.